# Display base64 string image as a hyperlink

Tags: java, html, css, image, base64

I am trying to display an image that is already converted into a base64 string as a link inside "a href" tag.

Java Method:

```
public void TakeScreenShot (String ScenarioName, String Description,JsonHtmlDataHelper jsonHtmlDataHelper)
{
    TakesScreenshot takeScreenshotDriver = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
    byte[] screenshotData = takeScreenshotDriver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    JsonObject jsonObjectHtmlReport = new JsonObject();
    jsonObjectHtmlReport.addProperty("ScenarioTest", ScenarioName);

    String imageData = Base64.encodeBase64String(screenshotData);
    String imgTag ="<img src=\"data:image/png;base64, " + imageData + "\" width=\"200\" height=\"150\"/>";
    System.out.println(imageData);
    jsonObjectHtmlReport.addProperty("TestStepDescription", imgTag);
    jsonObjectHtmlReport.addProperty("TestStepResult","PASSED");
    jsonHtmlDataHelper.AddProperty(jsonObjectHtmlReport);
}
```

The above method displays the image in HTML correctly but I want to add a link that redirects the page to the this image. According to the requirement, I cannot store the image anywhere.

I have tried the following:

```
<a rel=\"group\" href='#' onclick=\"$.fancybox.open({href:'data:image/png;base64," +imageData + "'})\">Click here</a>;

<a width=\"550\" height=\"190\" href=/ onclick=\"onclick=location.href=\'data:image/png;base64," + imageData + "\'\">click here</a>;

<img src=\"data:image/png;base64, " + imageData + "\" width=\"200\" height=\"150\"/>;
```

Comment: Cant you modify your imgTag string to be surrounded by an <a> tag?

Comment: create a server side (java) uri which will read out the image and print it to the browser

Comment: it is a plain .htm file and it is not hosted on the server.

Comment: @HarrisJT : could you please explain what you mean by surrounding string by <a> tag?

Comment: @Vic you want to link the image to redirect to just that image? Without having it stored just have imgTag="<a href=\""+imageData+"\">" + <img src=\"data:image/png;base64, " + imageData + "\" width=\"200\" height=\"150\"/></a>";

Comment: @HarrisJT. The following code worked for me;
    String imgTag = "<a href=\"data:image/png;base64,"+imageData+"\">View Image</a>";

Comment: @Vic that's what I was getting at, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently have this:

```
String imgTag ="<img src=\"data:image/png;base64, " + imageData + "\" width=\"200\" height=\"150\"/>";
```

You can surround it with an `<a>` tag that links to the `data` URL:

```
String imgTag ="<a href=\"data:image/png;base64," + imageData + "\"><img src=\"data:image/png;base64," + imageData + "\" width=\"200\" height=\"150\"/></a>";
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm trying to use it in my React project and wrote following code - `<a target='_blank' href={'data:image/jpg;base64,' + this.state.schemeImageBase64}><img width='500px' src={'data:image/jpg;base64,' + this.state.schemeImageBase64}/></a>`. Image is shown correctly, cursor icon is shown as it is for links, but when I click image - nothing happens, only console shows error "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL". Solved by opening new tab with base64 image using JavaScript - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46672702/1927853

Answer (score 3):

just  tag with href link will open blank page.
You need add `download="namefile.png"` into `<a>`

So it will look like this: `<a href="data:image/png;base64,..." download="abrakadabra_iLoveCats.jpg">download id</a>`