# Base64 Image open in new tab: Window is not allowed to navigate Top-frame navigations to data URLs

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In new chrome versions I got this error:

`Window is not allowed to navigate Top-frame navigations to data URLs`

The image looks like that (contains data in the url):
`data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/4QBYRXhpZgAA...`

I really need to open it in a new tab. **The iFrame solution isn't relevant**

Comment: a relevant link from Mozilla corporation describing the ways Data URLs will not work. https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/11/27/blocking-top-level-navigations-data-urls-firefox-59/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A javascript solution:

```
var newTab = window.open();
newTab.document.body.innerHTML = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNk+M9QDwADhgGAWjR9awAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" width="100px" height="100px">';
```

There's a lot of ways that you can change the way window.open() behaves, check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). It also shouldn't be hard to create some css/html that will mimic the way Chrome displays images in new tabs. The ability to load `data:` URLs was removed for security reasons, so you're out of luck if you're looking for a way to do that.

Comment: What about "save image as"? It doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Prefer using `var newTab = window.open(); newTab.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><body>..."); newTab.document.close();`. This sets doctype correctly, and avoids an unclosed document which breaks e.g. devtools.

Answer (score 17):

You can use this function to open any base 64 data URI in a new tab:

```
function openBase64InNewTab (data, mimeType) {
    var byteCharacters = atob(data);
    var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    var file = new Blob([byteArray], { type: mimeType + ';base64' });
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL);
}
```

In your case with the image, you'd use it like this:

```
openBase64InNewTab('YOUR_BASE64_DATA', 'image/png');
```

Answer (score 0):

url adress bar is limited for chars. You can only show "data:image/png;base64,.." string on page Or..

save it with a tag with attribute like  `download="iLiveCats.jpg"`

Your code will be like this: `<a href="data:image/png;base64,..." download="abrakadabra_iLoveCats.jpg">download id</a>`